# Loop to create multiple pandas dataframes within time periods named using variable names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

So I have a dataframe (dftxt) of about 2.2 million text entries with columns 'date' (a datetime object that includes hours and minutes) and 'text' (a string).

I have a list of 20 event dates and I want to create 40 dataframes with the rows within 6 months before each event and separately 6 months following each event. (I recognize that one event is used twice but I'd still like separate duplicate dataframes)

the events

```
ten1event1 = datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 15)
ten1event2 = datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 27)
ten1event3 = datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 10)
ten1event4 = datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 11)

ten2event1 = datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 25)
ten2event2 = datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 22)
ten2event3 = datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 7)
ten2event4 = datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 24)

ten3aevent1 = datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 22)
ten3aevent2 = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 9)
ten3aevent3 = datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 11)
ten3aevent4 = datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 5)

ten3bevent1 = datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 25)
ten3bevent2 = datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 29)
ten3bevent3 = datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 1)
ten3bevent4 = datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 19)

ten4event1 = datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 14)
ten4event2 = datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 23)
ten4event3 = datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 11)
ten4event4 = datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 25)
```

So what I want to do is loop through the df select all rows with dates within 6 months prior and create a new dataframe, then select all rows with dates within 6 months after and create another dataframe.

I'd like the dataframes to be named preten1event1 or postten1event1 etc.

What I have so far is:

```
events = [ten1event1,ten1event2,ten1event3,ten1event4,ten2event1,ten2event2,ten2event3,ten2event4,ten3aevent1,
          ten3aevent2,ten3aevent3,ten3aevent4,ten3bevent1,ten3bevent2,ten3bevent3,ten3bevent4,ten4event1,
          ten4event2,ten4event3,ten4event4]

for x in events:
    dfpre = dftxt.loc[(dftxt['date'] >= x - relativedelta(months=6)) & (dftxt['date'] <= x)]
    dfpre = dfpre.reset_index()
    dfpre.drop(columns=['index'], inplace=True)
    f"pre{x}" == dfpre
    
    dfpost = dftxt.loc[(dftxt['date'] >= x) & (dftxt['date'] <= x + relativedelta(months=6))]
    dfpost = dfpost.reset_index()
    dfpost.drop(columns=['index'], inplace=True)
    f"post{x}" == dfpost
```

It seems to run (far too quickly to actually be doing what I want I think), and then the expected dataframes don't exist

NameError: name 'preten1event1' is not defined"

I think it has something to do with this line of code     `f"post{x}" == dfpost`but idk how to do it and haven't been able to find anything with my searches.

I am just creating static dataframes, and I don't need variable variables I don't think.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your statement `f"pre{x}" == dfpre` is outright bad. You are intending to assing a variable name on the fly, which does not work this way. And it is also syntactically weird, as `==` is a comparison, not an assignment.

Comment: Thanks, yea I figured that was incorrect but was the only thing I could think of. I used the comparison ```==``` as the assignment ```=``` threw me an error. I am just trying to teach myself and couldn't find anything

Comment: don't use variable variable names. use a list instead, or a dict. hope the other article (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) helps a bit in explaining what (not) to do and pros and cons

Comment: Initialize a dictionary `dic` before the loop, then use `dic[f"pre{x}"] = dfpre`, and `dic[your_name]` to access it. This is the pythonic way to do this.

Comment: Thanks so much! the dictionary way proved very useful!